# not all code paths return a value, for loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, methods, return

This code will compare *usernames* and *passwords* that are stored in a text file. I think it is because of the for loop, it is probably simple but I cant see it.

```
public int loginCheck()
{ 
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    string[] users = File.ReadLines("Username_Passwords").ToArray();
    //line of text file added to array 
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------

    for (int i = 0; i < users.Length; i++)
    {
        string[] usernameAndPassword = users[i].Split('_');
        //usernames and passwords separated by '_' in file, split into two strings

        if (_username == usernameAndPassword[0] && _password == usernameAndPassword[1])
        {
            return 1;
            //return 1, could have used bool
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Remove else statement. If everything will be ok it return 1 and break loop. If not, program go out from loop and return 0.

Comment: This isn't really answering your question so I don't want to post an answer but you can one line this method using LINQ. public int loginCheck() => File.ReadLines("Username_Passwords").Select(x => x.Split('_')).Where(x => x.Length == 2).Any(x => _username == x[0] && _password == x[1]) ? 1 : 0;  I'd also suggest returning a bool because we're not using C++. (Edit: I see someone else said the same thing.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't return any value if `users` is an *empty* array.

```
string[] users = File.ReadLines("Username_Passwords").ToArray();

// if users is empty, users.Length == 0 and the loop isn't entered
for (int i = 0; i < users.Length; i++) 
{
   ...
}  

// no value is returned 

return 0; // <- suggested amendment
```

probably, you have to add `return 0;` below the loop

As the further improvement you can re-write the method using *Linq* (return `1` if file contains *any* record with required *username* and *password*, `0` otherwise):

```
public int loginCheck() {
  return File
    .ReadLines("Username_Passwords")
    .Select(line => line.Split('_'))
    .Any(items => items.Length >= 2 && 
                  items[0] == _username &&
                  items[1] == _password) 
   ? 1
   : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add return 0; after your loop, no return block is reached if users is of size 0.

```
    public int loginCheck() {
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------
        string[] users = File.ReadLines("Username_Passwords").ToArray();
        //line of text file added to array 
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------
        for (int i = 0; i < users.Length; i++) {
            string[] usernameAndPassword = users[i].Split('_');
            //usernames and passwords separated by '_' in file, split into two strings

            if (_username == usernameAndPassword[0] && _password == usernameAndPassword[1]) {
                return 1;
                //return 1, could have used bool
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Apologies, I merely corrected the question asked. I edited the answer to reflect it.

Comment: this will cause multiple returns after each iteration.